# Problems with an editing function in my database

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I have some issues with my program in visual studios.
I am currently learning c++ on a beginner stage and have a task due for tonight.
My main problem lays in the edit function, where edited information either overwrites the entire database or it adds upon as a new variable.
My wish is to allocate the string I want to edit, and replace the old information with the new.
I am aware that my way of coding may be out of date, but bear with me :)
I'm also programming for a Norwegian audience so my information output will be in my native language.

To summarize: main problems are to view edited information in the display all function.

Project below:

```
void edit() {
    system("cls");
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string education;
    string newfname;
    string newlname;
    string neweducation;
    string decision;
    string vessel;
    int number;
    int FDID;
    int age;
    cout << "Skriv inn FDID til personen du vil redigere: ";
    cin >> FDID;
    string FDID2 = to_string(FDID);
    FDID2.append(".txt");
    ifstream employee(FDID2);
    while (employee >> fname >> lname >> education >> age >> vessel >> FDID) {
        cout << "Er dette riktig?[y/n]" << endl;
        cout << fname << ' ' << lname << endl;
        cin >> decision;
        if (decision == "y") {
            system("cls");
            cout << "Informasjon tilgjengelig:" << endl;

            int fnameLength = fname.size();
            int lnameLength = lname.size();
            int lengthTotal = lnameLength + fnameLength;
            cout << "Navn";
            for (int y = 1; y < lengthTotal; y++) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << "Alder";
            for (int z = 1; z < 2; z++) {
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << "Fartøy";
            cout << "FDID" << endl;
            for (int x = 1; x < lengthTotal + 20; x++) {
                cout << "-";
            }
            cout << ' ' << endl;
            cout << fname << ' ' << lname << ' ' << education << ' ' << age << ' ' << vessel << ' ' << FDID << endl;


            cout << "Hvis du ønsker å endre noe, skriv inn et av tallene nedenfor:\n 1. Fornavn: \n 2. Etternavn: \n 3. Utdanning: \n 4. Alder: \n 5. Fartøy: \n For å avslutte og lagre, skriv inn [0]" << endl;
            cin >> number;
            
                if (number == 1) {
                    cout << "Skriv inn fornavn:";
                    cin >> fname;
                    fname[0] = toupper(fname[0]);
                    cout << "skriv inn nytt nummer: ";
                    cin >> number;
                }
                if (number == 2) {
                    cout << "Skriv inn etternavn: ";
                    cin >> lname;
                    lname[0] = toupper(lname[0]);

                    cout << "skriv inn nytt nummer: ";
                    cin >> number;
                }
                if (number == 3) {
                    cout << "Skriv inn utdanning: ";
                    cin >> education;
                    education[0] = toupper(education[0]);
                    cout << "skriv inn nytt nummer: ";
                    cin >> number;
                }
                if (number == 4) {
                    cout << "Skriv inn alder: ";
                    cin >> age;
                    cout << "skriv inn nytt nummer: ";
                    cin >> number;
                }
                if (number == 5) {
                    cout << "Skriv inn fartøy: ";
                    cin >> vessel;
                    vessel[0] = toupper(vessel[0]);
                    cout << "skriv inn nytt nummer: ";
                    cin >> number;
                }
                if (number == 0) {
                    employee.close();
                    ofstream employee2(FDID2);
                    employee2 << fname << ' ' << lname << ' ' << education << ' ' << age << ' ' << vessel << ' ' << FDID << endl;
                    employee2.close();
                    ofstream dir("database.txt", ios::app);
                    dir << fname << ' ' << lname << ' ' << education << ' ' << age << ' ' << vessel << ' ' << FDID << endl;
                    dir.close();
                    main();
                }
                else
                {
                    main();
                }

        }
        if (decision == "n") {
            main();
        }
    }
}

void displayAll() {
    system("cls");
    string fname;
    string lname;
    string education;
    string vessel;
    int age;
    int FDID;

    
    cout << "Dette er alle ansatte i organisasjonen" << endl;
    cout << "--------------------------------------" << endl;
    ifstream dir("database.txt");
    while (dir >> fname >> lname >> education >> age >> vessel >> FDID) {
        cout << fname << ' ' << lname << ' ' << education << ' ' << age << ' ' << vessel << ' ' << FDID << endl;
    }
    system("pause");
    main();
}
```

Comment: This is way too much code! Please narrow it down to just the bit you have a question about, a [mre]. Also, what is your actual problem?

Comment: You cannot call `main()` by yourself. And all your variables are local, accessible only in one function, how do you want to edit the data if you don't have it?

Comment: Can you be more specific. First you say _My main problem lays in the edit function_ then later _main problems are to view edited information in the display all function._ ??

Comment: i use main() as a return to chosing new options in my database.
The data is saved as an individual file aswell as in the database. 
When I edit the file, it overwrites the information in the file but don't refresh the information in database.txt.
Issues that occurs is that it either just overwrites all information, also other employees information, or it adds the new information below the old information

Comment: Yes, but you are not allowed to do that. Calling `main()` is Undefined Behaviour. Compiler could add some extra initialization code in the beginning of `main()` for example. The problem of going back to menu would easily be solved with a loop.

Comment: it is alot easier to visualize if you want to try and run the program for yourselves?

Comment: Yksisarvinen, I think I understand what you mean. But how can I loop each void function to the main function at the very end of every void code?

Comment: I do not recommend you to call the main() function. Because the C++  standard says in §3.6.1.3: `The function main shall not be used within a program.` This means that once the program begins executing, `main` should never be entered again. I suggest you could set a flag and return it, such as `bool flag`, in the `edit` function. You could write the corresponding code by judging the `flag` in the `main` function, such as loop.